# Can RestEasy client proxy ignore some method parameters?

Tags: java, asynchronous, proxy, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm attempting to use RestEasy's ResteasyClientBuilder to build proxy's for an asynchronous endpoint. Is there a way to get the client to generate a proxy that doesn't include all parameters on the interface's methods? Specifically I'd like to not ask callers for @Suspended injected parameters.

Comment: I don't see `ClientProxyBuilder` defined anywhere. What class is that? Also the last sentence is confusing, you don't generally ask the client to supply the `@Suspended` parameters.

Comment: I've updated the class name for the builder. I'd like to not ask the client to supply the @Suspended parameter, but I'd also like to build my proxy off the same interface that I'm coding my endpoints against.